# Spring Boot AOP IllegalArgumentException with @target and custom annotation,

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, illegalargumentexception

My code generate IllegalArgumentException when pointcut "@target ..." + custom annotation used, but with "@within ..." + same annotation it runs without exceptions. I don't understand why @target doesn't work...

Project configuration: Spring Boot 2.5.2, Gradle 7.0.2.

> 2021-06-27 09:22:22.180  WARN 9252 --- [           main]
> s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages':
> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
> generate CGLIB subclass of class
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages:
> Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
> non-visible class; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Loggable annotation**

```
package org.example.demoforaop.aop;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {
}
```

**LoggingAspect**

```
package org.example.demoforaop.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);
   
    // None exceptions if exchange @target to @within
    @Pointcut("@target(org.example.demoforaop.aop.Loggable)")
    public void loggable() {
    }

    @Before("loggable()")
    public void loggingBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Logging before: " + joinPoint.toString());
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
package org.example.demoforaop;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoForAopApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    SimpleService simpleService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoForAopApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(simpleService.getString());
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```
package org.example.demoforaop;

import org.example.demoforaop.aop.Loggable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Loggable
public class SimpleService {
    public String getString() {
        return "This is simple string for demo.";
    }
}
```

**Exception**

:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)

```
2021-06-27 09:22:21.735  INFO 9252 --- [           main] o.e.demoforaop.DemoForAopApplication     : Starting DemoForAopApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-2ICTH86 with PID 9252 (E:\Java\_Projects\demo-for-aop\build\classes\java\main started by root in E:\Java\_Projects\demo-for-aop)
2021-06-27 09:22:21.735  INFO 9252 --- [           main] o.e.demoforaop.DemoForAopApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-27 09:22:22.180  WARN 9252 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages
2021-06-27 09:22:22.185  INFO 9252 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-27 09:22:22.205 ERROR 9252 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.example.demoforaop.DemoForAopApplication.main(DemoForAopApplication.java:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:209) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:467) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:341) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:290) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `@target()` can only be evaluated during runtime, i.e. it will be applied to all components, also Spring components. If you limit the scope via `within()`, the problem should go away. Try not to weave the whole world.

Comment: Thanks. But '@target' in pointcut limit to custom Loggable annotation only. Other classes hasn't this annotation. Is it possible to use '@target' with custom annotation or not?

Comment: If you don't want to take my advice, up to you. Did you even try?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I am quite sure I am right. But even if I am wrong, with your silence you are not going to get the question reopened and answered. I tried to be nice by pointing you to the correct answer. Please also be nice and provide feedback. Thank you so much.